# Absolute position content within a responsive slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to do this for a while now and not having any luck with it. I have a responsive content slider. But i want to absolutley position content within the slider. I thought this would be fairly straight forward as the wrapper seems to have position relative already set to it.

However it seems to be the JS slider works out the height of the elements within the wrapper. However the images are overlapping so i need them to be position absolute. I've tried giving a max-width to the slider which works and floating on the images to the left and then giving the other absolute positioning. However this doesn't seem to work in FF. I have so far managed to get it work in Chrome.

Here is the slider i'm using - http://bxslider.com/

Here is a basic outline of my HTML/CSS:

This is CSS for my elements within the slider:

```
.slider.imageLeft {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}


.slider.imageRight {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}

<ul id="{{ slider_instance.name }}" class="slider">
   {% for slide in slider_slides %}
   <li>
    <div class="imageLeft">
      <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}images/exterior2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="imageRight">
      <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}images/exterior2.jpg">
    </div>

    </li>   
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The `<li>` has position relative set to it by the JS. Let me know if you need anymore detail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now managed to sort the issue with using floats and negative margins. Works much better for responsive sliders. e.g.

```
.slider .imageLeft {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -3.05085%;
    width: 57.2881%;
}

.slider .imageRight {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 45.7627%;
}
```

The above example won't make a great deal of sense to anyone without seeing the actualy slider. However I would advise using a negative margin rather position absolute within a responsive slider.

Hope this helps someone going forwards.